# Можно ли в python вызывать методы цепочкой через точку?

Tags: python, ооп, методы, функциональное-программирование

Есть ли способ в python заменить такой вызов методов

```
obj.f(obj.g(obj.p(x)))
```

на такой

```
bj.f.g.p(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверно так не рекомендуется делать, но решение нашлось:

```
class Moo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._call_stack = []

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        # Вызывается каждый раз, когда обращаются к классу "через точку"
        val = object.__getattribute__(self, attr) # Получает значение self[attr]

        if callable(val) and attr[0] != '_':
            # Если это функция, и не начинается на '_'
            self._call_stack.append(attr) # Добавляет название в стек
            return self # <-- это позволяет накапливать названия,
                        # и в конце цепочки вызвать самого себя
        
        return val

    def __call__(self, *args):
        # Вызывается, когда экземпляр класса пытаются вызвать как функцию
        stack = self._call_stack
        self._call_stack = []

        result = object.__getattribute__(self, stack.pop())(*args)

        while (len(stack)):
            result = object.__getattribute__(self, stack.pop())(result)

        return result

    def a(self, x): print('Calling: a'); return 2 * x
    def b(self, x): print('Calling: b'); return 3 * x
    def c(self, x): print('Calling: c'); return 4 * x
    def d(self, x): print('Calling: d'); return 5 * x    

m = Moo()

print( m.a.b.c.d(1) ) # 120, ура!
```

Если ищем "любой способ, лишь бы не вложенность", можно так:

```
class Moo():

    def nest(self, *fn_args):
        fn_list = list(fn_args)

        def __chain(*args):
            result = getattr(self, fn_list.pop())(*args)

            while (len(fn_list)):
                result = getattr(self, fn_list.pop())(result)

            return result

        return __chain

    def a(self, x): print('Calling: a'); return 2 * x
    def b(self, x): print('Calling: b'); return 3 * x
    def c(self, x): print('Calling: c'); return 4 * x
    def d(self, x): print('Calling: d'); return 5 * x

m = Moo()

print( m.nest('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')(1) )

"""
>>> Calling: d
>>> Calling: c
>>> Calling: b
>>> Calling: a
>>> 120
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dict = kwargs
        self.stack = []
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in self.dict:
            raise AttributError
        a = A(**self.dict)
        a.stack = self.stack + [self.dict[attr]]
        
        return a
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self.stack.pop()(*args, **kwargs)
        for func in self.stack[::-1]:
            res = func(res)
        return res

a = A(len=len, str=str)

print(a.len.str(100))
```